# "x87 register return with x87 disabled" のエラーが出る

Tags: gcc

コンパイルオプションに `-mno-80387` を付け、`double` と `long double` の
計算を行うソースコードをコンパイルするとエラーが発生します。

```
int main()
{
        double d = 3.0F;
        d /= 1.5L;
        return 0;
}
```

コンパイルエラー

```
$ gcc -mno-80387 a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:4:4: error: x87 register return with x87 disabled
    4 |  d /= 1.5L;
```

利用している `gcc` のバージョンは以下の通りです。

```
$ gcc -v 2>&1 | grep 'gcc version'
gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
```

clang では同様の現象がでないのですが、何かオプションを付ければ
回避できる類のものでしょうか ?

Comment: cygwin32-gcc4.5.3 / cygwin64-gcc11.3.0 だとエラー出ませんし実際 `fdivrp` 命令の代わりに `call __divxf3` が生成されています。でも今どき FPU を使わない理由がないので XY 問題かも？　なぜ `-mno-80387` を指定しなければならないのかから入ったほうがよさそう...

Comment: ありがとうございます。特に必須というわけではないので、オプションを外せば済むのですが、clang では出なかったので ちょっと気になって詳しい人に質問してみました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cygwin32 / cygwin64 の gcc で `-mno-80387` つきで提示コードをコンパイルすると除算に `__divxf3` なるライブラリ関数の呼び出しが生成されました。そして `undefined reference to '__divxf3'` なるリンクエラーになってしまいました。ということはコンパイラは `-mno-80387` に対応していても、それが必要とするランタイムライブラリ関数が用意されていないということです。

いかにも gcc 依存なランタイムライブラリ関数名っぽいので `gcc-11.2.0` のソースコードを調査してみました。 `__divxf3` なる関数は `gcc-11.2.0/libgcc/config/ia64/lib1func.S` だけにあります。ということは今はすたれてしまった IA64 (Itanium) にしかこのランタイムライブラリ関数は実装されていないようです（ IA64 は x86 / x86-64 とは違うアーキテクチャです）
# 要するに x86 や x86-64 では FPU が必ずあるので `nofpu` でコンパイルする理由が一切ないってこと

ということで Debian ディストロでは実行環境が対応していない機能（ `-mno-80387` でコンパイルしたバイナリを実行することができないということ）は、コンパイル時点でエラーになるよう親切心で配慮がなされているということだと思われます。

ちなみに `lib1func.S` 中のコメントを見ると 80bit 浮動小数点数の計算という記載があって、これは確かに 8087/80387 の仕様ではあるのですが x86 あるいは x86-64 では 80bit 浮動小数点数は扱わないわけで、質問者氏のいうところの `long double` が何 bit であるかは案件と実行環境の仕様とを十分に検討しないとまずそうです。

# WinXP についてきていた Space Cadet が 80bit 浮動小数点数に依存していて 64bit 浮動小数点数でコンパイルすると動きが全く違ってゲームにならない・・・なんて記事をどこかで読んだような記憶が

---

同様 `cygwin64-clang-8.0.1-x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus` で `clang -S -mno-80387 a.c` を試したところ、普通に `fdivrp` 命令が生成されており `-mno-80387` には効力がないことがわかりました（ `gcc` との互換性のためだけに `-mno-80387` は受け付けるが無効ということ）。当然リンクエラーも発生しませんし実行できます。 Debian でもコンパイルエラーが出ないはある意味当然かも。

Comment: clang では無視されていたために問題がなかったのですね、すっきりしました。詳しい解説をありがとうございました。